# dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS, problem with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, torch

I am trying to import torch, transformers and sklearn in my jupyter. The problem is that when I import sklearn first, I get dlopen error while import other two libraries. I realized that I need to import torch and transformers before sklearn but in this situation I get error while importing sklearn. The error is follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py:48
     47 try:
---> 48     from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
     49 except ImportError as e:

ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 4
      2 from torch import nn, optim
      3 from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
----> 4 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,f1_score
      5 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      6 from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer, AdamW, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py:81
     70     # We are not importing the rest of scikit-learn during the build
     71     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
     72 else:
   (...)
     78     # later is linked to the OpenMP runtime to make it possible to introspect
     79     # it and importing it first would fail if the OpenMP dll cannot be found.
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
---> 81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
     82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py:50
     48     from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
     49 except ImportError as e:
---> 50     raise_build_error(e)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py:31, in raise_build_error(e)
     29         else:
     30             dir_content.append(filename + "\n")
---> 31     raise ImportError(
     32         """%s
     33 ___________________________________________________________________________
     34 Contents of %s:
     35 %s
     36 ___________________________________________________________________________
     37 It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.
     38 
     39 If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
     40 to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
     41 `make` in the source directory.
     42 %s"""
     43         % (e, local_dir, "".join(dir_content).strip(), msg)
     44     )

ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /home/Something/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__pycache__               __init__.py               _check_build.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Also, I install sklearn via pip and I can import it individually without any problem.
I really appreciate it if you help me with this issue.

As I mentioned I tried to change the order of my imports and it helps me with torch and transformers but not sklearn.